# How to update time in current item if slot 1 and slot 2 are selected using SharePoint 2010-2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow2013

What is the workflow to update my date/time field if both slot 1 and slot 2 are checked in my Sharepoint form for Requested Slots?

Slot 1 date would be start time 05/01/2023 2:00 PM    end time 05/01/2023 3:00 PM and
Slot 2 date would be start time 05/01/2023 3:00 PM    end time 05/01/2023 4:00 PM

Is it possible if they select both slots that the end time for slot one updates to 4:00 PM